# Draw multi object diagram in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-shape

I'd like to achieve drawing a diagram just like the image attached but I'm having trouble drawing the red vertical rectangle on the right along with putting other objects on top. The biggest concern is the to do with numerous different screen sizes of Android devices. I fully understand what I'm trying to achieve during the process, which includes the objectives below. All help would be highly appreciated.

- 1 red rectangle on each side of the screen (right hand side I don't know how to draw there)
- 7 grey boxes in between the red vertical rectangles need to be equal in width
- a black vertical line needs to be in between the rectangles just like in the image above
- a text box showing a number needs to be in the center of each grey rectangle along with little red ones
- I also want to be able to reuse the diagram in future so I can fill the little boxes with red or black whenever I want

[image]

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <my.package.name.ComplexDiagram
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class ComplexDiagram extends View {


    private int measuredWidth, measuredHeight;
    private Paint mGreyRectPaint, mBlackLinePaint, mRedRectPaint;
    private RectF mGreyRect, mBlackLineF, mRedRectF;


    public ComplexDiagram(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null, 0);
    }

    public ComplexDiagram(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public ComplexDiagram(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyle) {

        mGreyRectPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mGreyRectPaint.setColor(0xFF3C3C3C);
        mGreyRectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        mBlackLinePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mBlackLinePaint.setColor(0xFF000000);
        mBlackLinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        mRedRectPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mRedRectPaint.setColor(0xFFCC3333);
        mRedRectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        measuredHeight = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        measuredWidth = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);

        setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (measuredHeight == 0 || measuredWidth == 0)
            return;

        canvas.drawRect(mGreyRect, mGreyRectPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mBlackLineF, mBlackLinePaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mRedRectF, mRedRectPaint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do box 1 and 7 need to have 6 rectangles, or can they use 8 like the rest of them?

Comment: They need to have 6 exactly as seen in the image. There are other drawings I'd like to achieve so I think we should discuss this in chat so I can show them to you. :-)

Comment: @BojanKseneman I was told before not to overload the activity with views and that it is better done in 1 class. I'm thinking more towards the '1 class' method however I would see both methods drawn and pick from the 2 options.

Comment: Every project should have a BaseActivity class, a class that all others extend from. Same goes to the Fragment. Not sure what they told you. Anyway, I'm at the moment really busy with my masters degree, so I'm unable to do this right now. Will try when I have a little more time.

Comment: Have you done anything with SAR images? :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do it this way

Put this in your XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#CC3333" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#808080" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1D1D1D" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#808080" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box1"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box2"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/box1"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box3"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/box4"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box4"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="#CC3333" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box5"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box6"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/box5"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box7"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/box8"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box8"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1D1D1D" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#808080" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box1"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box2"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/box1"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box3"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/box4"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box4"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box5"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box6"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/box5"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box7"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/box8"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box8"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1D1D1D" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#808080" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box1"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box2"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/box1"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box3"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/box4"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box4"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box5"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box6"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/box5"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box7"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/box8"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box8"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1D1D1D" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#808080" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box1"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box2"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/box1"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box3"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/box4"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box4"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="5"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box5"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box6"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/box5"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box7"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/box8"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box8"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1D1D1D" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#808080" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box1"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box2"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/box1"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box3"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/box4"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box4"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="6"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box5"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box6"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/box5"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box7"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/box8"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/box8"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1D1D1D" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#808080" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="7"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/red_background" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#CC3333" />

</LinearLayout>
```

for red rectangle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#CC3333" />

</shape>
```

Comment: Do you know a proper solution for solving [this other issue programmatically (in Java using canvas not XML)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037260/how-to-add-rectangles-on-top-of-existing-rectangle-in-canvas)? I've spent months trying to solve this issue but have had no luck and the answers that have been given don't solve the problem either.