# Draw multiple rectangles with dividers in-between

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-canvas

I'm trying to draw the image below but I'm not sure as to how to draw the grey and black rectangles. The red rectangles I've done perfectly hence would be grateful for someone to tell me hat can be done to achieve the following:

- 7 grey rectangles to be the same width
- 6 black rectangles to be 1px each
- all of the above to be drawn in between the red rectangles so that it looks **exactly** like the image blow.

Please try to avoid using pixel numbers for the x position of the grey and black rectangles if you can as I want the drawing to look the same for all screen sizes.

All help would be highly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

**What I'm trying to achieve**
[image]

**What I've achieved so far**
[image]

**Project code**

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //red shapes
        mRedRect0F = new RectF(0, 0, 10, measuredHeight);
        mRedRect1F = new RectF(getWidth() - 10, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        //grey shapes
        mGreyRect0F = new RectF(10, 0, getWidth() / 7, measuredHeight);
        mGreyRect1F = new RectF(10, 0, getWidth() / 7 - 20, measuredHeight);
        mGreyRect2F = new RectF(10, 0, getWidth() / 7 - 20, measuredHeight);
        mGreyRect3F = new RectF(10, 0, getWidth() / 7 - 20, measuredHeight);
        mGreyRect4F = new RectF(10, 0, getWidth() / 7 - 20, measuredHeight);
        mGreyRect5F = new RectF(10, 0, getWidth() / 7 - 20, measuredHeight);
        mGreyRect6F = new RectF(10, 0, getWidth() / 7 - 20, measuredHeight);

        //black shapes
        mBlackRect0F = new RectF(0, 0, 1, measuredHeight);
        mBlackRect1F = new RectF(0, 0, 1, measuredHeight);
        mBlackRect2F = new RectF(0, 0, 1, measuredHeight);
        mBlackRect3F = new RectF(0, 0, 1, measuredHeight);
        mBlackRect4F = new RectF(0, 0, 1, measuredHeight);
        mBlackRect5F = new RectF(0, 0, 1, measuredHeight);
        mBlackRect6F = new RectF(0, 0, 1, measuredHeight);


        //draw red shapes
        canvas.drawRect(mRedRect0F, mRedRectPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mRedRect1F, mRedRectPaint);

        //draw grey shapes
        canvas.drawRect(mGreyRect0F, mGreyRectPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mGreyRect1F, mGreyRectPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mGreyRect2F, mGreyRectPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mGreyRect3F, mGreyRectPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mGreyRect4F, mGreyRectPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mGreyRect5F, mGreyRectPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mGreyRect6F, mGreyRectPaint);

        //draw black shapes
        canvas.drawRect(mBlackRect0F, mGreyRectPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mBlackRect1F, mGreyRectPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mBlackRect2F, mGreyRectPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mBlackRect3F, mGreyRectPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mBlackRect4F, mGreyRectPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mBlackRect5F, mGreyRectPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mBlackRect6F, mGreyRectPaint);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can be easily achieved using a LinearLayout in conjunction with weights and horizontal orientation.

Comment: Need to see how it's done / prefer to do it programmatically (as I'll be using this with other components in my activity). Bear in mind that other rectangles and text will be drawn on top of this in the near future

Comment: it will easily achieve through linear layout

Comment: Please have a look at this image and tell me if the same would apply for that as this what I'm trying to achieve. [link to desired image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113281/draw-multi-object-diagram-in-fragment?noredirect=1#comment48450263_30113281)

Comment: You dont even need the dividers, just set background black and give a margin of 1-2dp between each rectangle on left.  That is if you go with the xml way. I would refrain posting xml as you specify that you need it to be done programatically.

Comment: I don't mind XML also but I'd need to see how it is done + my background will be white anyway hence I would prefer to have dividers

Comment: yes it's possible give me some time i will post answer for you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approch with Rect is maybe too much, if you want to do it with code, something like this should do the job:

```
public class Rectangle extends View {
    private final Paint mBackPaint = new Paint();
    private final Paint mRedPaint = new Paint();
    private int mSideRectWidth = 10;

    public Rectangle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mBackPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRedPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mSideRectWidth = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.side_rect_width);
    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (getWidth() == 0)
            return;

        setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

        //draw black line
        int boxWidth = (getWidth() - 2 * mSideRectWidth) / 7;
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            canvas.drawLine(mSideRectWidth + boxWidth * i, 0, mSideRectWidth + boxWidth * i, getHeight(), mBackPaint);
        }

        //draw left rectangle
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, mSideRectWidth, getHeight(), mRedPaint);

        //draw right rectangle
        canvas.drawRect(getWidth() - mSideRectWidth, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), mRedPaint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Yours proved to be the best as the other 2 cause a 'too many views' warning. Do you know a proper solution for solving [this other issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037260/how-to-add-rectangles-on-top-of-existing-rectangle-in-canvas) I've spent months trying to solve this issue but have had no luck and the answers that have been given don't solve the problem either.

Answer (score 1):

here is full fledged answer it is perfect for you,

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#CC3333" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#808080" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1D1D1D" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#808080"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1D1D1D" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#808080"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1D1D1D" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#808080"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="3" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1D1D1D" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#808080"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="4" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1D1D1D" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#808080"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="5" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1D1D1D" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#808080"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="6" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1D1D1D" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#808080"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="7" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#CC3333" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Brilliant. What about putting stuff on top just like in the this image?: [link to desired image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113281/draw-multi-object-diagram-in-fragment?noredirect=1#comment48450263_30113281)

Comment: red rectangle  is image and how many red rectangle in one box??

Comment: It needs to look exactly like the drawing you see in that question

Comment: 6 rectangles in boxes 1 and 7; 8 rectangles in boxes 2-7

Comment: ok actully i'm leaving for the day but give me some time i will do it for you.

Comment: i will do it before that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77718/discussion-between-jignesh-jain-and-macaronlover).

Comment: Do you know a proper solution for solving [this other issue programmatically (in Java using canvas not XML)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037260/how-to-add-rectangles-on-top-of-existing-rectangle-in-canvas) I've spent months trying to solve this issue but have had no luck and the answers that have been given don't solve the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small smaple, This is not a full fledged answer but should be helpful to grasp the idea. Please modify according to your needs:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#DDFF44" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="02dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#DDFF44" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="02dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#DDFF44" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="02dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#DDFF44" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you know a proper solution for solving [this other issue programmatically (in Java using canvas not XML)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037260/how-to-add-rectangles-on-top-of-existing-rectangle-in-canvas) I've spent months trying to solve this issue but have had no luck and the answers that have been given don't solve the problem either.